# exec.Command returns exit status 2 using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, exec

I'm trying to list directory content on s3 using aws cli. When I run my command in terminal it works so cli is configured correctly. However when I try to run it with exec.Command().Output() it does not work.

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

const (
    bucketName = "some-bucket"
    dirPath    = "data/entity/"
)

func main() {
    s3Path := bucketName + "/" + dirPath
    output, err := exec.Command("aws", "s3 ls s3://"+s3Path+" --recursive").Output()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(output)
}
```

Stdout:

```
exit status 2
[]
```

Comment: When you run the `aws` command in the terminal and then do an `echo $?`, what do you get?

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas "When I run my command in terminal it works so cli is configured correctly" So the answer is 0

Comment: `"s3 ls s3://"+s3Path+" --recursive"` is 4 separate arguments, you can't put them in a single string. You're also ignoring Stderr which would print an error or usage information.

Comment: @JimB so if I write it like this -> output, err := exec.Command("aws", "s3", "ls", s3Path, "--recursive").Output() the difference is just process hanging in terminal when I run compiled binnary.

Comment: @JimB It'll finish eventually but it's taking so long.

Comment: @MatusKacmar: so read the stdout/stderr, turn on debug logging, try a different command, etc. You need to do some debugging, but using correctly formatted arguments isn't going to cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error when calling `aws s3 copy ....` command using Go.

solution is quite simply, split your command with `space`, then call it in Go.

e.g.

```
// aws s3 ls s3://some_path --recursive 
exec.Command("aws", "s3", "ls", "s3://some_path", "--recursive")
```